# How to simulate next Stripe billing cycle with Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel-4, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I want to see what happens when a user's next billing cycle fires to make sure that my GST calculations are correct. Maybe my terminology is wrong, but I can't seem to find any clear documentation for performing this action. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trigger the next billing cycle for a subscription directly. What is usually recommended is to create a subscription with a trial period of a few minutes. This automatically creates a $0 invoice for the trial period. Then, once the new billing cycle starts a few minutes later, you'll get the new invoice and you can verify that the GST calculations are correct at that point.